# Sampling an image to get point pattern

Tags: spatstat

Here is an example where the authors have taken this image:

[image]

and analyzed using spatstat. To do that, they extracted the coordinates as it could be seen [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2015/BioC2015/BioC2015Oles.html#47). I would like to do the same and I am wondering how one could get a sample point pattern out of an image like this. Directly converting the image into a ppp object creates lots of artifacts.

The manual in their R package BioC2015Oles doesn't seem to exist. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too vague to really understand. Could you please provide some example code/pictures to explain exactly what you have now and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I added the image with further details.

Comment: How many points do you expect to reduce the example to? Could you maybe draw the relevant regions overlaid on the plot (just a rough drawing using the mouse is fine)?

Comment: I edited the entire post to reflect the bigger problem I am facing with. I thought if I sample in the small window I may get a sample point pattern for the image by moving the window, but there may be smarter solutions to the larger question I am having. Thanks for thinking through.

Answer (score 1):

The `spatstat` package assumes you have already processed your image and ended up with a list of coordinates and possibly some attributes (marks) associate with each pair (x,y). Ideally you should also have a window of observation indicating where the points potentially can occur. There is a raster/image formats in `spatstat` called `im` which can store an image/raster, but it is many used to store auxiliary information from the experiment, which can be used to explain the occurrence or absence of points in areas of the observation window and not to do image processing per se.

To convert a noisy microscope image to e.g. a list of cell centres people usually use various image processing tools and techniques (watershed, morphological opening and closing, etc.). The presentation you refer to seems to build on the R package `EBimage` (which is on BioConductor and does have a manual), and you can try to extract the cells using that. Alternatively there are other packages in R or entirely different open source systems focusing on image analysis such as [QuPath](https://qupath.github.io/), [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome) and many others. I cannot really guide you as to which one is the better tool for your task.

Comment: Yes, I realized this. I tried the EBImage and used image processing techniques to extract the point pattern. Thank you so much. I guess I can now start using `spatstat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
library(raster)
x <- brick('tLh2E.jpg')
#plotRGB(x)
```

All cells with coordinates:

```
xyz = rasterToPoints(x)
head(xyz)
#       x      y tLh2E.1 tLh2E.2 tLh2E.3
#[1,] 0.5 1103.5     222     222     224
#[2,] 1.5 1103.5     214     214     216
#[3,] 2.5 1103.5     223     223     225
#[4,] 3.5 1103.5     220     220     222
#[5,] 4.5 1103.5     197     197     199
#[6,] 5.5 1103.5     198     198     200
```

Or a sample:

```
s1 <- sampleRandom(x, 100, xy=TRUE)
s2 <- sampleRegular(x, 100, xy=TRUE)
```

To look at the locations of the samples

```
plotRGB(x)
points(s1[, 1:2])
points(s2[, 1:2], col='red', pch=20)
```

To create an image from a regular sample

```
r <- sampleRegular(x, 1000, asRaster=TRUE)
plotRGB(r)
```

For stratified sampling you would have to define the regions. You could draw them with `raster::drawPoly()` followed by `rasterize`, or model them see `raster::predict`. Here a very simple, and perhaps not very good, approach based on eye-balling. It turns out that the second, "green", layer (from the red-green-blue image) has most of the information. This gets you close:

```
r <- reclassify(x[[2]], rbind(c(0,100,1), c(100,175,2), c(175,255,3)))
plot(r, col=c('red', 'blue','gray'))
```

You can now do the following to find out which color each point has:

```
extract(r, s1[,1:2])
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance I can view the sample data as an image?

Comment: The random sample does not have an 'image" structure. But I have added some code for display and for a regular sample that can be represented as an image (raster).

Comment: But I suppose the random sampling is uniform right? How do I sample only from the "red" region or the "blue" region?

Comment: Yes uniform. See expanded answer for stratified sampling